# Mostrar siempre globo indicador de valor con el Slider de la librería MaterialDesign

Tags: android

Intentaba realizar algo parecido a lo que muestra Google con un tal `Discrete Slider` [[ENLACE]](https://material.google.com/components/sliders.html#sliders-discrete-slider)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al pensar que era algo 'que seguro que ya está echo', busqué hasta encontrar con una alternativa bastante recomendada, `MaterialDesignLibrary` [[ENLACE]](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary), de la cual la parte que me interesa es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero... está librería tiene un error al pasar el gradle es que un recurso se llama igual que uno de la nueva versión de la de android de soporte, por lo tanto, tomé la misma librería que ya tiene corregido con el nombre de recurso de un fork del mismo: [[ENLACE]](https://github.com/vajro/MaterialDesignLibrary)

Está me funciona bien, al menos para lo que yo la utilizo.

**La cuestión está en: ¿cómo habilitar para siempre el globo indicador de valor del slider, y que esté no puede ser 'deslizado'?**

Mi código Java está así:

```
/* ... Código ... */

mDiscreteSlider.setMin(0);
mDiscreteSlider.setValue(new Random().nextInt(100));
mDiscreteSlider.setMax(100);

/* ... Código ... */
```

Mi código XML está así:

```
/* ... Código ... */

<com.gc.materialdesign.views.Slider
    android:id="@+id/discreteSlider"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    materialdesign:max="100"
    materialdesign:min="0"
    materialdesign:showNumberIndicator="true"
/>

/* ... Código ... */
```

Comment: es decir, lo que quieres es boquear el slider ?

Comment: Bloquear y mostrar el globo fijo